# Get the number of connected nodes from a csv file that shows their relations

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I have a large `csv` file that is in the format:

```
ServerID|AppID
   01   |  01
   01   |  02
   02   |  02
   02   |  03
   02   |  04
   03   |  04
```

I am using this data in a `d3` force layout as shown in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aZH2Gl82XFic0SSXbqPT). The key bit of code to get the relations between the servers and apps (I.E. what apps are on what servers) is:

```
links.forEach(function (link) {
    link.ApplicationName= nodeByName(link.ApplicationName, "A");
    link.Servername = nodeByName(link.Servername, "S");

    edges.push({ source: link.ApplicationName, target: link.Servername })
});

function nodeByName(name, SorA) {
    var groupNo = 0;
    switch (SorA) {
        case "A":
            groupNo = 1;
            break;
        case "S":
            groupNo = 2;
            break;
        default:
        groupNo = 0;
    }
    return nodesByNames[name] || (nodesByNames[name] = { Name: name, group: groupNo });
}
```

which generates a unique list of servers and apps to create the nodes, and a separate list (`edges`) which has the relations between the servers and apps and is used to create the lines linking the nodes.

I want to be able to set the radius of the server nodes based off the number of apps running on them. I am struggling to think of an elegant way to get and store this information in the current system. Is there anything in `d3` already that can help here, or can someone see a way to do this given the current code?

Comment: so basically the amount of edges connected to it ?

Comment: yes, I'm struggling to see a nice way to calculate that.

Comment: Would you not be able to add simply `nodesByNames[link.Servername].count++` to the `forEach` loop, and initialize the `count` property to zero? Then just reference that when you're drawing the circles and setting their radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/gtAcJinltdjkgu1MEPmY?p=preview

```
var circles = node.append("circle")
  .each(function(d) {
    d.amountOfNeighbours = 0;
    link.each(function(e) {
      console.log(e)
      if (e.source.Name == d.Name) { //if the source of the link is this node, amountOfNeighbours++
        d.amountOfNeighbours++
      }
      if (e.target.Name == d.Name) { //if the target of the link is this node, amountOfNeighbours++
        d.amountOfNeighbours++
      }
    })
  })
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.amountOfNeighbours * 2;
  })
```

Basically go through all the links for and check how many link to the selected node like so :

```
.each(function(d) {
  d.amountOfNeighbours = 0; //set an attribute
  link.each(function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    if (e.source.Name == d.Name) { //if the source of the link is this node, amountOfNeighbours++
      d.amountOfNeighbours++
    }
    if (e.target.Name == d.Name) { //if the target of the link is this node, amountOfNeighbours++
      d.amountOfNeighbours++
    }
  })
})
```

And then use this value : `d.amountOfNeighbours` as the radius. I multiplied it by 2 as the value was fairly small :)

```
 .attr("r", function(d) {
   return d.amountOfNeighbours * 2;
 })
```

Hope that helps

Comment: ah awesome! thanks! this is exactly what i had in mind. I was thinking to only apply this for the server nodes, but that's just a simple check when i set the radius, so i can do that. I havent been doing javascript that long (only the last month or 2) and i still struggle sometimes to understand what `d` is in the function. so in your `.each(function(d){`... is `d` each circle?

Comment: yes 'd' is the current object you are on. You could put any string here. For example, I have used e above. And when you do d.amountOfNeighbours = 0; I am just giving that element an attribute called amountOfNeighbours and giving it a value of 0.

Comment: @JabbaWook expanding a bit on the previous comment, the `d` is simply a convention, because it represents the data bound to the element (which is bound when you call `.data(...)`. There is also another property, commonly called `i`, for index. E.g. `function (d, i) { ... }` which is the position of the element in the current selection. Finally, within the function the `this` keyword scopes to the actual html element associated with the object. These three things combined make the d3 inline functions very powerful!